# Split The Column which is delimited into separate Rows in Teradata 14

Tags: sql, teradata

Can any one help me in solving this. In a table, I have the data like this right now.

[image]

How do i split the column Nodes which has delimiter TTBFA-TTBFB-TTBFC-TTBFD into 4 rows with other columns being same.

california region GAXAEB  102,520,000   18.71  4    8/30/2014

california region TTBFA    92,160,000   23.33   3    9/13/2014

california region TTBFB   92,160,000   23.33   3    9/13/2014

california region TTBFC   92,160,000   23.33   3    9/13/2014

california region TTBFD   92,160,000   23.33   3    9/13/2014

The value for column NODES is not always 5 characters , It may vary like below

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use (whatever number is your max number of nodes) `UNION ALL` statements and `SUBSTRING` with INSTR for the possible locations for a node

try something like:

```
        SELECT region_name, nodes AS node, 
               sgspeed, sgutil, portCount, WeekendingDate
        FROM t
        WHERE instr(nodes,'-') = 0
        UNION ALL
        SELECT region_name, SUBSTRING(nodes  FROM instr(nodes,'-',1,1) +1 FOR instr(nodes,'-',1,2)-1) AS node, 
               sgspeed, sgutil, portCount, WeekendingDate
        FROM t
        WHERE instr(nodes,'-') > 0
        UNION ALL
        SELECT region_name, SUBSTRING(nodes  FROM instr(nodes,'-',1,2) +1 FOR instr(nodes,'-',1,3)-1) AS node, 
               sgspeed, sgutil, portCount, WeekendingDate
        FROM t
        WHERE instr(nodes,'-',1,2) > 0
        UNION ALL
        SELECT region_name, SUBSTRING(nodes  FROM instr(nodes,'-',1,3) +1 FOR instr(nodes,'-',1,4)-1) AS node, 
               sgspeed, sgutil, portCount, WeekendingDate
        FROM t
        WHERE instr(nodes,'-',1,3) > 0
    ...
```

Comment: Hi Beth  The column Nodes is not always 5 characters , This is just an example . It can vary from column to column.

Comment: is the dash delimeter the same?  like AA-BBB-CCCC-DDDDD

Comment: Yes dash is the delimiter for all the data.

Comment: I think you'll need Instr, still with multiple UNIONs.  Do you know the max number of nodes in the nodes column?

Comment: Hi Beth , It is a varchar(500) field. The max is see is 15 nodes in a column with delimiter.

Comment: yeah, I can't test the syntax without the schema, etc.  Glad it works!

Answer (score 8):

The function INSTR usually implies you're running TD14+.

There's also the STRTOK function, better use this instead of SUBSTRING(INSTR).

And instead of up to 15 UNION ALLs you can also cross join to a table with numbers:

```
SELECT region_name, STRTOK(nodes, '-', i) AS x
FROM table
CROSS JOIN
 ( -- better don't use sys_calendar.CALENDAR as there are no statistics on day_of_calendar
   SELECT day_of_calendar AS i
   FROM sys_calendar.CALENDAR
   WHERE i <= 15
 ) AS dt
WHERE x IS NOT NULL
```

And you can utilize STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE in TD14, too:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table AS t1
JOIN 
(
   SELECT * 
   FROM TABLE (STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE(table.division, table.nodes, '-')
      RETURNS (division VARCHAR(30) CHARACTER SET UNICODE
              ,tokennum INTEGER
              ,token VARCHAR(30) CHARACTER SET UNICODE)
              ) AS dt
 ) AS t2
ON t1.division = t2.division
```

Hopefully this is for data cleansing and not for daily use...

Comment: This should be the accepted answer ! Thank you dnoeth !

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine.

```
select  
REGION_NAME,
case when POSITION('-' IN Nodes) = 0  then NODES else SUBSTRING(Nodes,0,POSITION('-' IN Nodes)) end as node, 
SgSpeed, 
SgUtil,
PortCount, 
WeekEndingDate 
FROM table

UNION 

select
REGION_NAME,
SUBSTRING(nodes  FROM instr(nodes,'-',1,1)+1 for instr(nodes,'-',1,1)-1) AS node, 
SgSpeed, 
SgUtil,
PortCount, 
WeekEndingDate
FROM table
WHERE instr(nodes,'-') > 0

UNION

select
REGION_NAME,
SUBSTRING(nodes  FROM instr(nodes,'-',1,2)+1 for instr(nodes,'-',1,1)-1) AS node, 
SgSpeed, 
SgUtil,
PortCount, 
WeekEndingDate
FROM table
WHERE instr(nodes,'-') > 0

UNION

select
REGION_NAME,
SUBSTRING(nodes  FROM instr(nodes,'-',1,3)+1 for instr(nodes,'-',1,1)-1) AS node, 
SgSpeed, 
SgUtil,
PortCount, 
WeekEndingDate 
FROM table
WHERE instr(nodes,'-') > 0
```