# SQL Specific LIKE ANY String Search

Tags: sql, teradata, sql-like

So I'm in Teradata trying to pull any products that have more than 1 color-related name, as seen in the code snippet here:

```
SELECT
pt.product_number,
COUNT (CASE WHEN ot.option_name like any ('%green%', '%red%', '%blue%') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as differentColorCount
FROM product_table pt
JOIN option_table ot on ot.product_num = pt.product_num
HAVING differentColorCount > 1
GROUP BY 1
```

This is running fine, but the problem that I'm realizing is that a product might have a hundred different "Red" options for instance.  (Red-1, Red-2, Red-3, etc).  But I only want a count of when *two* of the different color strings are present for a single product.

So instead of **LIKE ANY** what I really need is **LIKE ANY TWO**.  If *both* Red AND Green are present, count 1.  If *both* Blue AND Purple are present, count 1.

I realize I could do a really long list where I do dozens of **LIKE ALL**s in every possible combination, but that doesn't seem like it will scale well if I need to check for, say 100 different colors instead of 6?

If anyone has any insight on this I would be incredibly grateful. Thanks in advance for any help you can offer!  :)

Comment: You shouldn't be storing multiple options in a single string.

Comment: what does your database look like? To Gordon's point are you storing all values in a single field?

Comment: if as gordon suggest you are storing multiple values in `option_name` you need convert that string to multiple rows https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29105836/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows-in-teradata

Comment: No, the options are broken out in another table, I just removed some JOIN clutter to try to make the issue a little clearer.  Basically I'm checking the Option Names in the break-out table for multiple colors, for each product.

Comment: I pasted a fuller version with the table JOIN at the end of the question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize a regular expression to extract the color and then apply a distinct count:

```
Count (DISTINCT RegExp_Substr(option_name, '(green|red|blue)')) AS differentColorCount
```

This is similar to your `like any ('%green%', '%red%', '%blue%')`, but returns the actual matching color instead of TRUE/FALSE.

The`'(green|red|blue)'` search pattern seperates defines three alternative search strings and returns the first match.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with RegExp_Substr, is it creating an array and then cycling through them looking for a given number of matches within the array?

Comment: @ender777: This extracts one of those listed substrings when it's found, simply run it without the count to check the result.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks again!  Heading to Google for an hour to two (or five) to learn RegExp.    :)

Comment: @ender777: caution, this might end in 100++ hours, Regular Expressions are a  programming language :-)